# Is it possible to listen if a function was fired in another .js file

Tags: javascript, paperjs

Is is possible to listen if a function was fired up in another .js file?

For example `function foo()` was fired.

Is it possible to run a piece of code everytime `foo()` is run without placing the code I want to run within that function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to know about is javascript events.  How to create your own event and trigger it.

[See this answer for a good start](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2490876/3501422)

What you want to do is have the function trigger an event (let's say `funcCalled`) and in your main app add a listener for the that event.  The listener can then dispatch instructions based on what you need.

Answer (score 4):

*Although dops above pointed me to the right answer, I'll drop a cross-browser compatible way of doing this.*

**First we need to dispatch an event from the function that is-to-be listened if fired.**

(The following snippet goes into the function to be listened on)

```
// Create the event
var event = new CustomEvent("name-of-event", { "detail": "Example of an event" });
document.dispatchEvent(event);
```

**Second, we need to add an eventListener to listen if the function was fired:**

```
document.addEventListener("name-of-event", function(e) {
  console.log(e.detail); // Prints "Example of an event"
});
```

**Now this works just fine in FF/Chrome but IE doesn't support it. So we need to create a [polyfill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyfill) for it.**

Just put this function anywhere in your script and IE will support the above snippets of code.

```
(function () {
  function CustomEvent ( event, params ) {
    params = params || { bubbles: false, cancelable: false, detail: undefined };
    var evt = document.createEvent( 'CustomEvent' );
    evt.initCustomEvent( event, params.bubbles, params.cancelable, params.detail );
    return evt;
   };

  CustomEvent.prototype = window.Event.prototype;

  window.CustomEvent = CustomEvent;
})();
```

**Sources:**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent

[How to trigger event in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript/20548330#20548330)